# Database Projects with Visual Studio 2012 Exist?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

With the upcoming release of Visual Studio 2012, are there project templates for managing SQL 
Server scripts?

i.e. I have tables, views, stored procedures that I want to store and maintain in TFS by including them in a database project which maintains scripts.

Looking at the RC version of 2012 I do not see this type of project template any more.  Any workarounds or information on how to manage scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new SQL Server Data Tools should be installed with the RC out of the box. It should provide you the ability to connect to an existing DB via SQL Server Object Explorer (open in the "views" menu), as well as the ability to import an existing DB into a project, or create a new DB project. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=VS.103).aspx) link to MSDN gives a very thorough overview of how to use SSDT. Hope that helps!

EDIT: SQL Server projects are in File -> New -> Project -> Templates -> Other Languages -> SQL Server

Comment: Yes, I see that option but I have found it easier to have one of the older Database style projects which allow me to manually create/modify scripts which I would deploy via 'Execute Sql'.  The template you mention requires direct connection to SQL Server as well as performs deploys which via builds which we do not want to use.  In addition, we have databases that manage many applications and so building a database project which just has specific tables/sprocs etc. is much more difficult.

There must be another alternative considering we want to only manage sql scripts themselves.

Comment: The short answer is that you can use/execute scripts in the same manner by adding a script that is "not in build". You can change the properties of existing scripts to the same. Once you have done this, you can execute the script, choose its target DB from the menu on the top of the screen once you open it.  Another option would be to create a blank project and add your scripts to it, then run the scripts directly against the SQL Server in the SSOX. As an aside, the true power of SSDT is in its ability to perform DB development declaratively. You may want to consider taking it for a test drive